why does istringstream fails specifically on the first input
Trying to sum all rows and cols (valid doubles only) of the following file by making a vec of vecs out of it and then using an istringstream to validate doubles:
18,459,45A,AG7,490,486
4A 2,65,-87,432,-43,0
67,3G,5T,TEA,COFFEE,5
3.14,2.71,654,2334,66,8
a,b,c,d,18,f
cafecafe,4,-4,3,2,6

using the code:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void parse_csv(string fname) {
    ifstream file(fname);
    vector<string> lines;
    vector<vector<string>> data;
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        data.push_back(vector<string>());

        stringstream ss(line);
        string val;
        while (getline(ss, val, ',')) {
            data.back().push_back(val);
        }
    }

    // print data
    for (auto row : data) {
        for (auto col : row) {
            cout << col << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < data.size(); r++) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int c = 0; c < data.front().size(); c++) {
            std::istringstream ss(data[r][c]);

            cout << "curr data " << ss.str() << endl;

            double d;
            ss >> d;

            if (ss.fail() || !ss.eof())
                std::cout << "Failed to parse " << data[r][c] << endl;
            else
                sum += d;
        }

        std::cout << "Row " << r << " sum: " << sum << endl;
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < data.size(); c++) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < data.front().size(); r++) {
            std::stringstream ss(data[r][c]);
            double d;
            std::string postfix;
            ss >> d;
            if (!ss.fail() && !(ss >> postfix))
                sum += d;
            else
                ss.clear();
        }

        cout << "Column " << c << " sum: " << sum << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    parse_csv("example.csv"); 
}

consider only the first for loop (because the two loops will be almost the same) ss always fails on the first 18, and swapping it with the 459 next to it also fails the 459, but then the 18 doesn't fail.
I tried swapping entries as I said, printing the state with .good() (it becomes bad after trying to flush ss into the double) and adding another item before it, that makes the new item fail but 18 to not fail.

What do you mean when you say that the input "always fail"? If the stream "fails" it usually means there's an error in the stream and you can't use it to read anything else (until you remove the error condition and clear the fail bit).

"consider only ..." -- no, you extract a [mcve] and post that, please. Also, be specific with what you observed, like e.g. output and exceptions. Don't just give us your interpretation! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

@Someprogrammerdude I declare a new stream each iteration. before trying to flush ss containing 18 (or probably any number in data[0][0]) into the double ss.good() returns 1, afterwards 0.

I haven't had the patience to read the code in its entirety, but it looks like the problem is the file format. Try saving it as an ASCII file.

Instead of if(ss.fail() || !ss.eof()) use if (ss >> d) { /* Success */ } else { /* Failure */ }

And you will get guaranteed failures, because e.g. AG7 can't be parsed as a double.

I'll bet the file begins with a BOM character.

Don't use std::vector<std::vector>.  The fields have different types.  Instead, create a class that models the record, i.e. has the same field and types as the data row.  Overload the operator>> in the class to read the structure.

Is AG7 a typo?  Is that field a text field, such as the row containing TEA, COFFEE?  Are all of your rows consistent in their field types?

I finally solved it. There was probably something going on with the csv file. I recreated the file with the same name, and just to be sure asked chatgpt to reproduce the text only using ascii

Don't use a std::vector<std::vector>.  You can only use this data structure if all of the fields have the same type, which in your case, they don't.
Instead, declare a class that models a row of the data, for example:
class Row_Data
{
    int m_column1;
    int m_column2;
    int m_column3;
    int m_column4;
    std::string m_column5;
    int m_column6;
};  

Your data can then be represented as a vector of rows:
std::vector<Row> database;  

Note:  The above class does not model your data since there are inconsistencies in your data.
A good idea is to overload operator>> to read your class members from an input stream.  Then your input could look like this:
std::vector<Row> database; 
Row              r;
while (data_file >> r)
{
     database.push_back(r);
}

